# Backspace key not working on jQuery UI Dialog input

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dialog, backspace

I have a jQuery UI Dialog with a form inside it. When I show the page, I set the focus on the first input of the form.

If I type some text, the input shows it, but if I press Backspace or Tab key, this keys don't work: Backspace doesn't delete content of the input field and Tab  doesn't focus on the next tabindex element.

However, if I click first on the dialog title bar, these keys now work.

I'm using Backbone views to show the DOM but I don't think this is causing the issue.

I test to change form and input fields CSS z-index property to a very high value but this doesn't work. Any idea?

EDIT: the problem only happens when two jQuery UI dialogs are visible. If only the dialog with the form is visible backspace and tab work, but I can't figure out how to solve it

Comment: Do you have any handlers for keyboard events? It sounds like they're intercepting the backspace key and preventing the normal behavior.

Comment: Yes, I have one handler to catch the Enter key, but no for these keys. And when I click on the dialog title bar, for example, it works.

Comment: You're going to have to post some code that shows what you're doing, and preferably make a jsfiddle so we can experiment with it.

Comment: I'm using backbone with lots of background code to manage views and models on JS and it's hard to post it in a JSFiddle.

Comment: Is all that stuff necessary to reproduce the problem? How do you expect anyone to debug your code for you if you don't show it to us?

Comment: I noticed that the problem only happens when two jQuery UI dialogs are visible. If only the dialog with the form is visible backspace and tab work, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Tried to reproduce that, don't have a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/E7T8Z/2/

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, except I only have one form visible. Clicking the title bar also fixes it for me.